# Executing windows azure web job

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, azure, c#-4.0, azure-webjobs

I create a small .exe that updates some tables in my database also create in azure, but all the times that I upload the `.zip` file required shows this error

[image: Bug]

Reading blogs I realized that some people are using the windows azure web job sdk, to upload their projects, it is worth to point it out that this library doesn't have a version for Visual Studio 2010, so it can't be used.

Is the use of the aforementioned sdk the only way to create and use console application web jobs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually you get the `failed to upload job` error if the zip file does not have the job exe *in the root folder*.

This often happens when you zip the Debug/Release folder instead of **its** contents.

You don't have to use the Azure WebJobs SDK for your job. Any console application will work.

Comment: More on non-sdk jobs: http://blog.amitapple.com/post/74215124623/deploy-azure-webjobs/

Answer (score 3):

> sdk the only way ...

No, WebJobs can run without the cloud SDK. To quote [Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingWindowsAzureWebJobs.aspx)

> You don't have to use the WebJobs SDK with the WebJobs feature of
>   Windows Azure Web Sites.

As to what the exact problem is...with VS2010 and Azure that is hard to say with what you have presented.

Answer (score 1):

WebJobs, since it sits on top of the Azure Web Sites service, it supports everything the Web Sites support.  Including: python, php, bash, powershell, node.js, .net, cmd, bat, etc...